# plot all columns of a text file with python (equivalent of -nxy option in xmgrace)

Tags: python, matplotlib, xmgrace

I have a text file with N columns (N unknown or quite large), say data.txt.
I would like to plot the last N-1 columns versus the first column with python.
In other words, how can I get python to work like a 'xmgrace -nxy data.txt'

many thanks in advance

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide what have you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.genfromtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to read the file, and then just plot in a loop, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

for i in range(data.shape[1]-1):
    ax.plot(data[:,0],data[:,i+1])

plt.show()
```